# Disable <a href> in runtime using Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

Using Bootstrap

```
  <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked col-sm-2 hidden" id="menu">
                <li role="presentation" id="LiNewsFeed"><a href="javascript:GetNewsFeed();">News Feed</a></li>
                <li role="presentation" id="LiStatusUpdate"><a href="javascript:StatusUpdate();">Update Status</a></li>
                <li role="presentation" id="LiWriteWall"><a href="javascript:WriteOnWall();">Post On Wall</a></li> 
                <li role="presentation" id="LiNotifications"><a href="javascript:GetNotifications();">Notifications</a></li>
                <li role="presentation" id="LiLogOut"><a href="javascript:LogOut();">Logout</a></li> 
  </ul>
```

In Javascript, I am disabling some of the `<li>` like the following:

```
 $('#LiNewsFeed').addClass('disabled');
```

The Item in the List actually LOOKS disabled, when when I click on it, **it actually calls the javascript function**, therefore, what I need is to disable the `<a href>` not just the `<li>`

I tried adding this after  `$(document).ready`:

```
$(".nav li.disabled a").click(function () {
                return false;
});
```

But it's not really doing anything.

What I need is to disable the `<a href>`  directly after disabling `<li>` in my Js code, and not to depend on a click event...

Seems like there is no way to disable an `<a href>`, so I need a way around it

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: use 

$(".nav li.disabled a").click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
});

Comment: @jQuery Thank you, but I want to disable the a object, and not depend on the click event, because it's getting mixed up within other events and not calling it right.

Comment: then you can unbind click event  

$(".nav li.disabled a").unbind('click') or in new version of jquery $(".nav li.disabled a").off('click')

Comment: check my answer may be it will help you

Comment: @HelpASisterOut Did you try my solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use below code. check working example [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/m56vL6am/)

```
$(".nav li.disabled a").each(function(){
     $(this).attr('href','javascript:void(0);');
});
```

Comment: If I call this from te browser console it works, but not from the code

Comment: did you check example?

Answer (score 1):

I would check on every link click if the parent has the disabled class.

```
$('.nav li a').click(function () {
    if($(this).parent('li').hasClass('disabled')) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
});
```

EDIT, following more info from OP I would suggest the following:

```
$('.nav li a').each(function() {
    var $this = $(this);

    // store reference of 'href' attr in case link is re-enabled
    $this.data('href', $this.attr('href'));

    if ($this.parent('li').hasClass('disabled')) {
        // remove href attribute disabling click
        $this.removeAttr('href');
    } else {
        // restore href
        $this.attr('href', this.data('href'));
    }
});
```

This code should be run after you add/remove the disabled class on li elements.

EDIT 2 - Rather than you calling functions from the href of `<a>` links, you could do something like the following:

```
var events = {
    '#LiNewsFeed': 'GetNewsFeed',
    '#LiStatusUpdate': 'StatusUpdate'
    '#LiWriteWall': 'WriteOnWall',
    '#LiNotifications': 'GetNotifications',
    '#LiLogOut': 'LogOut'
};

for (var selector in events) {
    if (events.hasOwnProperty(selector)) {
        try {
            $(selector).click(function () {
                // assuming function is global
                if (typeof window[events[selector]] === 'function') {
                    // call function
                    window[events[selector]]();
                }
                // this is needed if the a element still has a href attr
                return false;
            });
        } catch (e) {
            console.log('Invalid Selector');
        }
    }
}
```

This way you can control the calling of the function, and check whether it should be called without altering the element, perhaps stick an

```
if (!$(this).parent('li').hasClass('disabled')) {
    ...
}
```

around the function call.

Comment: But I am binding the action to the ahref inside the a href tag like the following <a href="javascript:GetNewsFeed();">. is there a way I can turn this into javascript:void() in runtime?

Comment: yeah, in that case you could do $(this).attr('href', 'javascript:void(0)'); or perhaps even remove it, $(this).removeAttr('href');

Answer (score 1):

As you are disabling `LI` in javascript (runtime), you should use `.on` to bind events on disabled links:

```
$(".nav").on('click', 'li.disabled a', function () {
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

can you convert the a into span?

(code not tested)

```
$(".nav li.disabled a").replaceWith(function() { return "<span>" + this.innerHTML + "</span>"; });
```